# What is the story behind the Asian female assassin?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, deutschland-83

Who was the Asian female assassin, playing a prostitute in episode 02 of  *Deutschland 83*? And why did she attack Martin, did she attack him thinking he was a West or East soldier?

What's the whole story with her? It was never explained, as far as I understood, except vaguely, they said, "Maybe she was KGB or a Chinese spy".

Answer (score 1):

She wasn't a prostitute; we see her earlier in the episode working as a waitress in the hotel. Given the fight she puts up, Martin presumes her to be an undercover agent, much like himself. As you say:

> Maybe she was KGB or a Chinese spy

That's the only context we get. I think it's reasonable to believe that other parties (besides the HVA) were interested in NATO's analysis. While I agree that it was a bit unsatisfying to just leave it there, I think the plot point that's being made is just how important that disk was.